# imakeidx Package ist file is not supported

Tags: imakeidx

I am using `imakeidx.sty` package to generate two type of index like `List of symbols, Index`.

The problem is `form.ist` file is not working.

My form.ist file is

```
headings_flag 0
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak"
item_01 "\\nopagebreak\n \\subitem "
item_12 "\\nopagebreak\n \\subsubitem "
item_x1 "\\nopagebreak\n \\subitem "
item_x2 "\\nopagebreak\n \\subsubitem "
delim_0 "\\quad "
delim_1 "\\quad "
delim_2 "\\quad "
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=symbols,title={List of symbols},options=makeindex -c -s form.ist symbols]
\makeindex[options=makeindex -c -s form.ist Sam_Ind]

\begin{document}

The sample\index[symbols]{$phi$} Index. The\index[symbols]{$\alpha$} sample Index. The sample Index. The sample Index. The sample Index. The sample Index. 

\newpage

The sample\index{Text Index One} Index two. The sample Index\index{Text Index two} two. The sample Index two. The sample Index two. The sample Index two. The sample Index two. 

\printindex[symbols]\markboth{List of symbols}{List of symbols} % Person index

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The `options=makeindex -c -s form.ist symbols` command is not working.

My required output is `index entry and Page number` in between `seperator` is `\quad` space.

But my current output is `index entry and Page number` in between `seperator` is `,`.

I would like to control through the `.ist` file. But the `.ind` file is not updated.

My required output and current output mentioned below mentioned figure:

[image]

Please advice how to get the `\quad` space separation.

Comment: what is `Sam_ind`? And`makeindex` in the options list is wrong!

Comment: "Sam_ind" is a  tex file name. MWE file name

Comment: The two type of ind file is generated. Sam_ind.ind, symbols.ind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the whole command line, so what the system tries to do is

```
makeindex makeindex -c -s form.ist symbols symbols
```

which is an error.

The `option` key wants just the options to be passed to `makeindex`:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=symbols,title={List of symbols},options=-c -s form.ist]
\makeindex[options=-c -s form.ist]
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is working excellent. Thank you for your awesome answers